# How to get timezone rules version used by datetime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timezone, zoneinfo

In John Skeet's [blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/03/27/storing-utc-is-not-a-silver-bullet/) about handling timezone information when storing future datetimes, he suggests storing the version of timezone rules in the database along with the local time and timezone id.

His example:

```
ID: 1
Name: KindConf
LocalStart: 2022-07-10T09:00:00
Address: Europaplein 24, 1078 GZ Amsterdam, Netherlands
TimeZoneId: Europe/Amsterdam
UtcStart: 2022-07-10T07:00:00Z
TimeZoneRules: 2019a
```

**In python, how do you get the version of timezone rules used by datetime?** For example:

```
date.astimezone(zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('US/Pacific'))
```

Comment: It is possible the rules are encoded someplace within the source code, have you looked?

Comment: [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html): "*By default, zoneinfo uses the system’s time zone data if available; if no system time zone data is available, the library will fall back to using the first-party tzdata package available on PyPI.*"

Comment: Related but rather old: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28279700/10197418

Answer (score 2):

The method of getting timezone rules depends on the library used to create the tzinfo instance.

If using pytz, the timezone database used is the Olson timezone database.

```
import pytz
print(pytz.OLSEN_VERSION)  # e.g. 2021a
```

When using zoneinfo, the system's timezone data is used by default.

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html): *By default, zoneinfo uses the system’s time zone data if available; if no system time zone data is available, the library will fall back to using the first-party tzdata package available on PyPI.*

There are two options:

1. Find a platform specific method of getting the version number
2. Setup zoneinfo with the tzdata library, which makes the timezone version number readily available.

For option 2:

To setup zoneinfo to ignore the system data and use the tzdata package instead, set the environment variable PYTHONTZPATH=""

The IANA version number is exported by tzdata:

```
import tzdata
print(tzdata.IANA_VERSION). # e.g. 2021e
```

Comment: concerning #1, on debian, that could be `apt list tzdata` - and parsing the output for the version etc. etc. - #2 might be preferable I think, assuming you can make sure to keep it up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

This is a POSIX-only solution, works with tzdata v.2018a+:

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path  
import re
import zoneinfo 


def get_system_tzdata_version():
    """
    Get the used tzdata version

    NOTE: Only supports tzdata versions 2018a and
    later, as the version info was added to tzdata.zi
    in tzdata version 2018a.

    Returns
    -------
    version: str | None
        The version of the system tzdata.
        If version could not be read from tzdata.zi,
        return None.
    """

    # This is a file that contains a copy of all data
    # in the tzdata database. It has been part of the
    # tzdata since release 2017c.
    tzdata_zi_fname = "tzdata.zi"

    if os.name == "nt":  # Windows
        raise NotImplementedError("Currently, only POSIX is supported")

    # Assuming we are in posix system
    for p in zoneinfo.TZPATH:
        p = Path(p)
        tzdata_zi = p / tzdata_zi_fname
        if p.exists() and tzdata_zi.exists():
            break

    with open(tzdata_zi) as f:
        contents = f.read()

    match = re.match(r"^\s*#\s*version\s+(?P<version>.*)\n", contents)

    if not match:
        # Could not find version string from the tzdata.zi file
        return None

    return match.group("version")
```

##### Explanation

- zoneinfo by default uses the system timezone information, which on POSIX systems is coming from the `tzdata` (system) package.
- The locations where `zoneinfo` reads for tzdata data are listed in [zoneinfo.TZPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html#zoneinfo.TZPATH)
- The version info of the tzdata database has been written to a file called `tzdata.zi` since tzdata version 2018a. [[tzdata NEWS](https://data.iana.org/time-zones/tzdb/NEWS)]